# Как сохраняется в памяти set <set <int>>?

Tags: c++, stl

Например,

```
set < set<int> , less<set<int>> > K;
```

Как `K` сохраняется в памяти? set сохраняется в памяти в отсортированом виде в виде бинарного дерева , а set< set< int > > в каком?

Comment: А что эти цифры означают?!  set сохраняется в соответствии с реализацией set, то есть какой алгоритм выбран для построения дерева.

Comment: ну например так set < set<int> , less<set<int>> > K; как "K" сохраняестя в пам'яти?

Comment: Как объект класса, который имеет определенные поля.  Для хранения элементов выделяется динамически память.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow может оформите как ответ (если можно добавить деталей)?

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните какой именно аспект сохранения объекта в памяти вас интересует?

Comment: set<int> сохраняется в памяти в отсортированом виде в виде бинарного дерева , а set< set<int> > в каком?

Comment: Для начала, нет никакой предписанной структуры данных для хранения. Поэтому в вашем вопросе речь может идти лишь о конкретной версии рантайма конкретного компилятора.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обычно `set<T>` реализуется с помощью [*двоичных деревьев поиска*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) ([binary search tree, BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)). Операции поиска, удаления и вставки имеют среднюю сложность *O(log n)*, также поддерживается итерация в остортированном порядке.

В случае вложенных множеств `set<set<T>>` в элементах дерева хранятся множества второго уровня. Множества второго уровня сортируются при помощи оператора сравнения `<`, который для множеств задан как [*лексикографический порядок*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA) ([lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)).